# Evaluating Colored Jones Polynomial of a trefoil knot

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Following arXiv:1211.6075v1 I want to calculate colored Jones Polynomial for trefoil knot. I have the formulas:

$ J_{\oplus R_i} = \sum_i J_{R_i} (K,q)$

$J_{R} (K^n, q) = J_{R^{\otimes n}} (K,q)$

I can decompose my representation $2 \otimes 2=1 \oplus 3$ and use $J_{1 \oplus 3} = J_1 \oplus J_3$ and $J_{2 \otimes 2} = J(K^2,q)-1$.
And here's my problem. I have no idea what $J(K^2,q)$ is and how to calculate it. I don't understand the statement:" $K_n$ is the n-cabling of the knot K, obtained by taking the path
of K and tracing it with a cable of n strands."

How can I calculate the polynomial of $K^2$ to get $J_3$ ?

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the operation of cabling a knot. Take a diagram with writhe $=0$, and replace the knot with $n$ parallel strands plus a twist to make sure they join up into a knot. Below is a $2$-cable of the figure $8$. To do a cable of the trefoil you need to add some kinks in the usual diagram first so that it has writhe $0$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What about the calculation of the polynomial for this knot? Do I just use skein relations? (This seems really hard though)

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to compute the Jones polynomial of a cable.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip anyway I could convince you to go into more detail about "adding kinks so it has writhe 0"? Just anything you can say at all would be great, I'm trying to understand what's going on and why

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa Adding a kink means a type I Reidemeister move. The writhe is defined to be the sum of the signs of the crossings, and you can always add kinks to make sure this is $0$.